# Router configured as repeater w/ directional antenna has good connection with host router, but connecting devices only momentarily recieve internet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, routing, wireless-router, dd-wrt

##### Background info

- I have two Linksys WRT-1900AC routers. One is configured as the host access point, with the stock Linksys firmware installed.
- The other 1900AC, located in an external building about 500 feet away
  from the host router, has DD-WRT firmware installed, is equipped with
  a 15 dB directional panel antenna, and is configured to act as a
  **non-bridged** wireless repeater for the host router.
- The repeater is set up with its own access point and credentials, but routes all traffic directly through to the host.
- The repeater's directional antenna is aimed almost directly at the host router, with good line-of-sight and only 1 wall in between the two.
- When doing a network scan with the repeater, DD-WRT reported that the measured RSSI from the repeater to the host was -60, which is sufficient reception for the application.

##### The problem

Devices connected to the repeater will immediately receive an internet signal, but will lose connection to the internet after almost exactly 45 seconds. **Disconnecting and reconnecting immediately restores internet access** for another 45 seconds. This happens regardless of the time of day (see below).

##### Attempts to fix/diagnose

I've double-checked all of my settings in DD-WRT, and as far as I'm aware the settings are basically set to their defaults minus the little configuration I had to do to make it a repeater. Scheduled reboots are disabled on both routers. I've also marked the repeater as a priority device in the Linksys firmware on the host router. I've reset and reconfigured both routers at least 3 times, but the problems mentioned above still persist. **Speed tests and packet tests also come back with good results (when they can finish) while connected to the repeater.**

I've also noticed that a similar issue also occurs when connected directly to the host router as well, where internet access suddenly drops but comes back after reconnecting, but the timing between dropouts seems to be longer (10-15 minutes) and usually happens in the afternoon or evening. I suspect it's just bandwidth throttling by the ISP and is a separate issue, but considering the similarities, I figured it was worth mentioning.

The problem in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/632865/internet-speed-with-dd-wrt-repeater-bridge) is similar, but as the top answer says, this is likely caused by the router switching between client and AP mode on just one antenna. This is not a problem with my repeater, as the 1900AC has two radios and is using both in its repeater configuration.

(I'm not nearby the repeater at the time of writing, but I'll update with the DD-WRT configuration later if it's needed.)

Comment: Any logs on either device that show something happening in that first minute? If almost the same problem happens when connected directly to the main router, that suggests the dd-wrt repeater is OK (there are dozens if not hundreds of dd-wrt builds to try, weekly iirc, but might not help). Can the repeater itself maintain a good internet connection with the main router (as a repeater now, or in client-only mode)?

Comment: @Xen2050 Haven't had a chance to comb the logs yet, but I'll do that as soon as I get the chance and report back. I don't think it's an issue with DD-WRT, because this is the second router this has happened with. The first was a Buffalo WHR-300HP which, while pretty old, has DD-WRT support directly from the manufacturer.

Comment: What’s a non-bridged repeater supposed to be? Does it create its own subnet? Does it do NAT to appear on the upstream network as a single device? // Do packet captures and, if equipped to do so, also capture Wi-Fi traffic.

Comment: Review the DD-WRT system log. DD-WRT has a shoddy docs section, so if unable to identify the issues you may want to try OpenWrt since it has a far more robust docs section on how to do a repeater. Also, the main running Linksys firmware is 5yrs out of date - put DD-WRT or OpenWrt on it so you have up-to-date security patches